# How do you enter unicode characters in Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, unicode

I am currently using the normal Evil keybindings (defaults). How do I enter unicode characters such as U+21d2 ⇒ ? In routine applications such as Gedit or Firefox, we can use `Ctrl+Shift+U 2 1 d 2` or in Vim, we can use `Ctrl+V u 2 1 d 2`. What is the equivalent in Spacemacs? I've tried `Ctrl+V u 2 1 d 2` as well as `Ctrl+V 2 1 d 2`. The first one just doesn't work whereas the second one stops after two letters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer is written for Spacemacs 0.105.19 with default keybindings.

Since you already know that `Ctrl+v` might be one way to do it, you can look at the documentation to understand what it does. In `Insert` mode, type `Ctrl+h` (help) then `k` (for `describe-key`) and then `Ctrl+v`. Amongst other things, this points out that

> The variable `read-quoted-char-radix' specifies the radix for this feature;
>   set it to 10 or 16 to use decimal or hex instead of octal.

You can click on `read-quoted-char-radix` and it will show you the current value and the default (which is `8`). Click on `customize` to change the value: set it to `16` for hex codes and `10` for decimal codes.

After you've set `read-quoted-char-radix` to `16`, you can use `Ctrl+v 2 1 d 2 RET`  in `Insert` mode to put in the ⇒ arrow. Using `SPC` instead of `RET` will give an extra space unlike other applications.

In normal editing mode (i.e., not `Insert` mode), you can also do a reverse lookup using `SPC i u` and typing say "rightwards double arrow" will give you several options such as ⇒ (rightwards double arrow), ⟹ (long rightwards double arrow) etc. You can pick an option and the character will be inserted at the cursor position.

Comment: wow you are replying to yourself like you were someone else :-D

Comment: I'm a bit star-struck right now :D. Actually I had asked this question in the Gitter chat a couple of months back and TheBB had nicely described the solution for me. Turns out I forgot the solution. So I retraced my steps and wrote down the solution step-by-step. Now I can't forget it :).